# How to install USB Wi-Fi driver from the cd in lubuntu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, cd

[I just bought external USB Wi-Fi and trying to install driver from cd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWh2S.png)

I don't know how to do this in Linux, in Windows simply just click autorun.exe and done.

Comment: please [edit], plug in your usb wifi adapter and copy/paste the output of `lsusb` and `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Also, in your screen shot, what is the contents of the Linux folder?

Answer (score 2):

Reputable hardware manufacturers push their drivers to the Linux kernel, so their hardware is automatically detected and just works for you. You should not need to install anything. Your dongle should simply work. Try it.

Compiling kernel modules yourself from source (which is likely what's on the CD) is possible, but that method fell out of favor over 15 years ago.

- This method is not used by any reputable Linux-supporting manufacturer today.
- This is not a task for beginners!
- The compiling tools that you need are NOT on the install image anyway. If you lack another means of network access, this is a chicken-and-egg problem.

**Advice**: If the WiFi dongle is not *automatically recognized* by your Ubuntu system, return it to your vendor and purchase one that is automatically recognized (there are many!)

- Do not give your money to manufacturers and vendors who don't provide proper Linux support (or who lied about it!)
- Support vendors who have a generous return policy. Occasionally, despite extensive research, you discover that some hardware is less-than-advertised or incompatible.